# django form not being saved to db

Tags: python, django

```
<div class="review-form">
    <h1 class="review-title">Add Review</h1>
    <form class="form" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div>{{ form.title }}</div>
        <textarea>{{ form.description}}</textarea>
        <br>
        <button class="submit-btn" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>


**forms.py**

from . import models
from django import forms

class gameReviewForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=24)
    description = forms.CharField(max_length=500)


**models.py**

from django.db import models
from django.db.models.fields import AutoField, CharField, TextField

class gameReview(models.Model):
    title = CharField(max_length=24)
    description = CharField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

**views.py**

def add_review(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.gameReviewForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            title = form.cleaned_data['title']
            description = form.cleaned_data['description']
            review = models.gameReview(title=title, description=description)
            review.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('home')
    else:        
        form = forms.gameReviewForm()   
    return render(request, 'main/add_review.html', {'form': form})
```

// I am trying to post data to the database but for some reason it's not actually working! Any help is greatly appreciated, the redirect doesnt execute so it seems to me that the form is somehow invalid

Comment: are u getting any errors ?

Comment: Have you tried to use a `ModelForm` or perhaps `gameReview.objects.create(title=title, description=description)`, note you don't need to call `save()` if you use `create()`.

Comment: Don't wrap `{{ form.description}}` in a `textarea` tag, the field will render it's own input with the correct attributes. If you want the field to be rendered as a textarea then change the field to a TextField

Comment: Add an else block for form.is_valid() that prints or logs the form.errors.  It will help with your debugging of the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using **is_valid** then you can't use **cleaned_data[ ]** in your view function . Django doesn't support this .

---

[views.py](/questions/tagged/views.py)

```
from .forms import gameReviewForm

def add_review(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = gameReviewForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():                
            form.save(commit = True)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/home')
    else:        
        form = forms.gameReviewForm()   
    return render(request, 'main/add_review.html', {'form': form})
```

Update your [views.py](/questions/tagged/views.py) and it will commit your data to the database and will redirect your HttpReponse .